# Recursion code in VBA

Tags: excel, recursion, vba

[image]

I am trying to run this code to calculate Q(n) at different Tn in the Equation 16.4 in the attached picture.But its not giving me the correct output. I would appreciate any help.  Note: delta1=delta2 =...deltan = dt=1 ( I have taken here ) and further divided S term by 10000 just because in the Equation it is in basis point i.e. 100th part of 1 %.

```
Function Bootstrap(S As Range, Z As Range, L As Double) As Double
Dim j As Integer
Dim a As Variant
Dim b As Variant
Dim n As Integer
Dim Q() As Double
Dim sum As Double
Dim P As Double
Dim dt As Double

n = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(S.Columns.Count, Z.Columns.Count)
a = S.Value
b = Z.Value
dt = 1
sum = 0
ReDim Q(0 To n)
Q(0) = 1

For j = 1 To n - 1
    P = (b(1, j) * (L * Q(j - 1) - (L + dt * a(1, n) / 10000) * Q(j))) / (b(1, n) * (L + a(1, n) * dt / 10000)) + Q(n - 1) * L / (L + a(1, n) * dt / 10000)
    sum = sum + P
    Q(n) = sum
Next j

Bootstrap = sum
End Function
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific than "it's not giving me the correct output"?

Comment: Infact Bootstrap i.e. Q(n) should always be between 0 &1 as its the probability but it even comes >1 sometimes also when I put the input and for n=1 the Bootstrap value Q(1) gives value error .  Input vectors that I put for  S matrix  is  50 77 94 125 133   & the corresponding  Z matrix 0.97 0.94 0.92 0.86 0.81 & L= 0.5.  This gives the output for Bootstrap =Q(n= 1 to 5 ) values correspondingly  as  #VALUE! 1.016264422 1.034891859 1.113982199 1.166501913

Comment: i see what you are up to now... try solving this recursively. In fact your text book already give you the recursive function. Hence just use it straight forwardly in VBA, no need to interpret it as a `For...Loop` sequence.

Comment: I think you have to change `Q(n)=sum` to `Q(j)=sum` in the for loop

Comment: Please check the modified code now but still the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To solve a recursive function you can write it this way, for example

```
Function Factorial(n as long) as long
    If n = 1 Then
        Factorial = 1
    Else
        Factorial = n * Factorial(n-1)
    End If
End function
```

Yes, you can see `For...Loop` can also do the Factorial calculation, but in your case, its much easier to use recursive solution.

Besides Eq 16.4 is intentionally written as a recursive function. It is not written as a summation function because it is harder to do so. If given to you is a summation function, then you can apply the `For...Loop` solution.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

```
Function Q(n as long) as double

    If n = 1 Then
        Q = 5
    Else
        Q = Z * ( L * Q_t - (L + d * S) * Q(n-1) ) / ( Z * ( L + d * S ) )
    End If

End Function
```

Notice that the function `Q` keep calling itself in `Q(n-1)` when `n>1`. That is called recursive solution.

(Check the formula. I might copy it wrong)

Comment: @Shenon . Would you please modify my code so that I could get what you mean precisely by recursive without for loop.

Comment: I would if I can. Honestly I'm not very sure about that function Q(). But I see `Q(t,T_j)` and `Q(t,T_j-1)` and the text ask to solve for `Q(t,T_j)`. This suggest using recursive solution. See my factorial example, its very straight forward.

Comment: @Shenon . You mean Q(n) =Q(n-1)* the j term(by putting n ) + Q(1) ? You can write Q(t,T_j) simply  as Q(j).not a problem.

Comment: Yes... `Q(n)` and `Q(n-1)`

Comment: Factorial is simple ..but this seems complicated a bit.. Am trying but not getting proper output..If you could modify this now after getting what exactly is Q() .

Comment: It doesn't matter how complicated the function is, as long as you have the recursive function in math form, just whack it in VBA

Comment: Perhaps the Fibonacci recursive solution will give you further insight. Try google it. Its elegant.

Comment: Tried this code as recursively but no positive result .                         Q(0) = 1
Q(1) = Q(n - 1) * L / (L + a(1, n) * dt / 10000)
  
Q(n) = (b(1, n - 1) * (L * Q(n - 2) - (L + dt * a(1, n) / 10000) * Q(n - 1))) / (b(1, n) * (L + a(1, n) * dt / 10000)) + Q(1)
    sum = Q(n)
Bootstrap = sum

Comment: I know recursive function but your code is not running to give the desired output.

Comment: like i say, i don't know credit curve and i am writing it wrongly. please check for yourself.

Comment: you dont need to know credit curve ..I am just talking mathematically. Please check the modified code what I have done now.

Comment: not quite right. u shouldn't declared Q as an array. Q should be the function name, replacing bootstrap. otherwise if you need a separate function to do this, its a good idea.

Comment: That doesnt make difference. I have done this before and it works.. Please tell me why it doesnt give the correct output .Please check the recursive formula or similar things.

Comment: Hello quant1, did you solve your problem? I mean, did you found a working recursive solution for your credit curve formula?